# Jax: Take derivative with respect to index of vector-valued argument

Tags: python, jax, autodiff

Does Jax support taking the derivate w.r.t. an index of a vector-valued variable? Consider this example (where `a` is a vector/array):

```
def test_func(a):
  return a[0]**a[1]
```

I can pass in the argument number into `grad(..)`, but I cannot seem to pass the index of a vector-valued argument like in the example above. I tried passing a tuple of tuples, i.e.,

```
grad(test_func, argnums=((0,),))
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in transform that can take gradients with respect to certain elements of arrays, but you can straightforwardly do this via a wrapper function that splits the array into individual elements; for example:

```python
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def test_func(a):
  return a[0]**a[1]

a = jnp.array([1.0, 2.0])
fgrad = jax.grad(lambda *args: test_func(jnp.array(args)), argnums=0)
print(fgrad(*a))
# 2.0
```

If you want to take a gradient with respect to *all* the inputs individually (returning a vector of gradients with respect to each entry), you can use `jax.jacobian`:

```python
print(jax.jacobian(test_func)(a))
# [2. 0.]
```

Comment: Very nice, this solves my problem directly. I hadn't thought about wrapping it in a lambda that takes a list and calls the function with an array. As you point out, using `jax.jacobian` is great when you need the differential w.r.t. all parameters (which I might need in the future).